# Display box on an input through clicking on img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that if i click on the image, then the box display in the input field using `$('.daterangepicker').show();`.

**On onclick:**

```
onclick="OpenDatePicker('DateAge')
```

**Markup:**

```
<span class="DateLabelImage" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="OpenDatePicker('DateAge')"><img class="calendarImage" src="../../img/StatImg.png"></span>
<input type="text" id="DateAge" placeholder="Click to open Date Box" class="AgeChangeInput range"/>
```

**Script:**

```
<!-- Call datepicker through image button -->
<script>
function OpenDatePicker(DatePicker)
{
    var classIt = '.' + DatePicker;
    alert(classIt);

    // Click on any Input Field.
    $(classIt).on('click', function()
    {
        alert('Good');
        // Show Box on click Date.
        $('.daterangepicker').show();
    });
}
</script>
```

I tried using:

```
.on('click', function()
```

but this is not working as i am not clicking on the input field instead i am clicking on the image.

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Comment: place on click for image

Comment: i will provide the jsfiddle shortly please wait.

Comment: ^^ rgodse has provided the jsbin.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/vikramjakkampudi/9NMgT/1/

```
function OpenDatePicker(DatPicke)
{
    var classIt = '#' + DatPicke;
    alert(classIt);

    // Click on any Input Field.
    $(classIt).on('click', function()
    {
        alert('Good');
        // Show Box on click Date.
      //  $('.daterangepicker').show();
        $('.ui-datepicker-div').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: when i click on the image i get the alert() but not get the datepiker. this works when i click on the the input. but i want through image.

Comment: @ Vikram Jakkampudi okay  but what if i want to show a div?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9NMgT/5/ please check this. i want to show this `dhsjdhs` one at a time. i.e when i click on the first imge i get this `dhsjdhs` and when i click on the 2nd image i get the 2nd `dhsjdhs` and 1st one hide. this is the real question i was asking. sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1):

click event should bind in ready or document.ready function .
another thing is 'DateAge' is an id not a class so you should call by '#' not '.'.
I thing following will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DateAge").click(function () {
            alert('Good');
            $('.daterangepicker').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: bu this is straight forward clicking on the input. i want to click on the image to make this happen/

Comment: in that case you may have this simply`function OpenDatePicker()
{ $('.daterangepicker').show();}`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `#` instead of a `.`. Secondly I can't find `.daterangepicker` in the markup. I did the change as I mentioned. Here is the link
http://jsbin.com/feyunagi/1/edit

Comment: hey you are getting the alert? i am clicking on the image but no response. i placed the alert() in the on click function.

Comment: Which alert are you not getting? You might not get the second alert coz you are using an `id` for the input box but querying using **class** selector.

Comment: i am talking about http://jsbin.com/feyunagi/2/edit. i put an alert but didn't get response. i changed the . with the #.

Comment: As per your code, first you should click on the image and then the input box and its working fine that way until and unless you want something else.

Comment: yeas but i just need to click the image. no click on the input.

Comment: I believe this is what you ultimately want to do. 
`$(classIt).focus();`